# Java couldn't find or load main class even if manifest is correct

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have Server.Launcher class in a jar file. Everything was working great - until it didn't.

Perhaps the problem is with new libraries I tried or some configuration error - but either

```
java - jar JavaServer.jar
```

or

```
java -cp JavaServer.jar Server.Launcher
```

return the same problem - Server.Launcher class missing. Except it is in the jar, and manifest is correct.

I am compiling the Jar on linux and running it on Windows.

Is it possible that some other missing class leads to this error? If so, is there any way to find out what is wrong?

Edit:

Here is my manifest file.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Server.Launcher
```

Main-Class: Server.Launcher

Edit2:

Ok. The problem is with two Jars I tried bundling up. Guess they had some unmet dependencies or something. Not sure how to fix it cause I need those jars.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have two, separate JAR files? Or did you create a single JAR file that contains two other JAR files? _Server.Launcher class missing. Except it is in the jar_ Obviously it's not, otherwise you wouldn't get that message. My guess is that you are looking at the wrong JAR file.

Comment: Run `jar -tvf JavaServer.jar` and verify that `Server/Launcher.class` is in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the source code for each of the JARs, and compile them together. Also, for good practice, do `-jar` instead of `- jar`.